# mvn failure on build

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build one of project using `"mvn package"` and I am always seeing an error. I installed maven in Ubuntu as `"sudo apt-get install maven"`

Below is the error I am getting:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single (create-archive) on project : Execution create-archive of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single failed: client id '11012121111423' is too large ( > 4013111 ) -> [Help 1]
```

What is wrong I am not able to understand at all.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is [a known problem](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/faq.html#tarFileModes) with the maven assembly plugin configuration.

[Since version 2.5](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-728) you must specify [tarLongFileMode=posix](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html#tarLongFileMode) for long file mode support.

Just edit the pom.xml and inside the `<configuration>` tag add:

```xml
<tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
```

so the whole tag will be like:

```xml
<configuration>
    <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
</configuration>
```

Comment: since it is a reflection call there is not enough info on the trace. Just look at the calls for the goal create-archive

Comment: or even better: open a ticket witth the trace on github

Comment: I have updated my answer. I believe I have found a  viable solution. Check it out :-)

Comment: well, the assembly plugin uses the TarArchiver class. TarArchiver docs explain it all (http://plexus.codehaus.org/plexus-components/plexus-archiver/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/tar/TarArchiver.html). It works on a "safe" mode unless you use TarLongFileMode (http://plexus.codehaus.org/plexus-components/plexus-archiver/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/tar/TarLongFileMode.html)  as I was showing on my answer before the edit, for long file (posix) support.

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't want to change the pom you can use

```
mvn clean install -Dassembly.tarLongFileMode=posix
```